# aws-sdk gem: "Could not find mini_portile-0.6.0 in any of the sources"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I had installed aws-sdk gem and i have some problem with a dependency.
When i launch the server everything works fine but when i launch the console i have this error:

```
Could not find mini_portile-0.6.0 in any of the sources
```

Although the gem is correctly installed:

```
$ bundle show mini_portile
/Users/Wedontplay/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@rails415/gems/mini_portile-0.6.0
```

I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.1.5
Any idea of what is happening?
Tx

Comment: I'm seeing a similar problem when I try to run rails, but I do not see the gem with 'bundle' but I do see it installed with 'gem list' and I have manually installed it to be sure.